# Restrict download of documents but enable editing

Tags: sharepoint-online

I want the users to edit document data  but not download them. Is it possible in SharePoint Online ?

Answer (score 1):

As a site owner, you can help secure data by setting the Offline Client Availability setting to No.

On the site, click Settings > Site Settings.

Under Search, click Search and offline availability.

In the Offline Client Availability section, select No.

To allow users to download content, set the Offline Client Availability option to Yes.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/prevent-users-from-downloading-content-from-a-site-e17bf52b-fa5d-41cf-9eb0-d3812542424e

Answer (score 1):

You can create a sensitivity label (compliance portal) and set "allow limited, web only access" (external sharing&conditional access) to block downloading for unmanaged devices. After publishing you can apply the label to a site or library.

This might also work (not tested) for a sensitivitylabel based on authentication context (external sharing&conditional access). You first have to create authentication context (AAD Conditional access) and create a conditional access policy with your requirements with the authentication context selected. Then you can apply it to your sensitivity label.