# Is there a way to restrict people of downloading documents, but allow them to print them in a SharePoint Online library?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, download, printing

What I would like to achieve here is the Restricted View permission level but with the option to print documents from libraries included in it.

Answer (score 1):

Per my knowledge, if you allow them to view/print the document, they will be able to download it. As you are using SharePoint Online, you if have the Azure Rights Management service (Azure RMS) from Azure Information Protection enabled, you will be able to apply Information Rights Management(IRM) to a list or library, and control the available behavior for users who download these files.

You can check it here:

[Set up Information Rights Management (IRM) in SharePoint admin center](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/set-up-irm-in-sp-admin-center)

[Apply Information Rights Management to a list or library](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/apply-information-rights-management-to-a-list-or-library-3bdb5c4e-94fc-4741-b02f-4e7cc3c54aa1)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by following the below steps,

1. Goto your library --> library settings --> permissions --> Click on Stop Inheriting Permissions. After that library will have a unique permission.

Note – By doing this, the library will not inherit the same permissions as the site.

2. Create one “View Only” group. Users added in this view only group will not be able to download the document or sync the document library in their system. Provide the name and the permissions level (view-only permissions) for this group.
3. Add users into your "View Only" group, for whom you want to restrict downloading.
4. After adding a user to View Only group, users will only be able to access the document but will not be able to download. But when they open the file in browser, then they can print it.

For information, refer the below link,

https://www.cloudfronts.com/restrict-download-and-print-option-for-sharepoint-online-document-library/

**EDIT**

You can set "Offline Client Availability" as **No** at your library level settings. Go to Library Settings --> Advanced settings --> select NO To download

But the above settings will not work for any users with contribute, edit, more permission level.

If you want to disable the download-option for your users, they should have View Only permission level. Permission levels Read and any greater include the permission for downloading a file.

View Only permission levels still includes the following permissions:

> View pages, items, and documents. Any document that has a server-side
>   file handler can be viewed in the browser but not downloaded. File
>   types that do not have a server-side file handler (cannot be opened in
>   the browser), such as video files, .pdf files, and .png files, can
>   still be downloaded.

Source: [Understanding permission levels in SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/understanding-permission-levels?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252fUnderstanding-permission-levels-in-SharePoint-87ecbb0e-6550-491a-8826-c075e4859848)

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this problem myself and tried Karthik Jaganathan's solution of making a View Only group, but it did not work - users were blocked from printing through the browser.

I have some large document libraries with 3 access levels: 1) Approvers/Editors (full access), 2) Authors (editing, but not delete rights), 3) Viewers (View). It do not want my Viewers to be able to edit documents at all, but they do need to print them to share with others. If I grant Restricted View they cannot print, but if I give them regular Read permissions they are able to download into the local app, modify the document and save a local copy. That's exactly what I am trying to avoid by using SharePoint - we cannot have divergent copies being circulated. I have discovered a few work-arounds, but none are as ideal as Microsoft just implementing this permission.

[Turn off Offline Client Availability](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/245643/110755). Unfortunately, this is at the site-level, so it applies to all document libraries and would restrict my authors, too. So, I could create a sub-site with this setting that only hosts this document library, but it would still block my Authors from local app capability and syncing the library. Wince Word on the Web is not as powerful as the local app, there are things they cannot do as well - like arranging images.

I could have two document libraries. One would house my working, editable documents as Word files for my Authors and Editors. The other would contain only published PDFs. This has its drawbacks, too. It adds a step for Editors to create the PDF in the other library, unless I build a Power Automate flow to do this automatically when they change the status to Published. That seems like unnecessary work and one more thing to maintain. Besides, PDFs can still be modified.

Tell my staff to NOT edit documents and always get the latest version directly from SharePoint, but I cannot enforce that - even with the threat of flogging.